# Entity framework load from view save to table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

sing **Entity Framework 6** (code first from db) I have some entities that I am getting from a sql view. The view contains a couple of calculated fields that I need to be able to display,
But I cannot save back to the view because of it doing a couple of joins and other things that will not let me save.

Is there any way, which makes sense, to read from the view, but save back to a table (the table being the same as the view minus the calculated fields)?

I know this is sparse on details, but I basically want to find out if this is possible, or if I should be doing it a different way.

**Thanks**

```
    [Table("SDWorkshop.vWorkshop")]
    public partial class Workshop
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Workshop()
        {
            Registered = new HashSet<Registration>();
            Waitlist = new HashSet<Waitlist>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Workshop_ID { get; set; }

        //removed a bunch of fields for berevity        

        public int? Capacity { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int? NumberRegistered { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int? ActualNumberRegistered { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int? EmptySeats { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public ICollection<Registration> Registered { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public ICollection<Waitlist> Waitlist { get; set; }
}
```

The caluclated fields are the ones marked database generated, that part works for saving back to the view, but sql generates an error because the view uses joins to fill those calculated fields.

Comment: This isnt really enough information for anyone to be of loads of help.  But i'll try:  I assume you have designed the table properly and that the Entity has a unique identifier.  you could just save the details back to this Entity in the table using direct SQL if your joining is complex and difficult to do thorugh the Entity Framework

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I would like to avoid using any sql in my code and stick with entities.  
Is it bad practice to make one entity for reading data (mapped to the view) and one for saving (mapped to the table)?

Comment: That would indeed be bad practice, and might cause you some issues down the line.  If you share the code behind the Entity / what you want it to do then perhaps myself or someone else could be more help

Comment: I added part of the code for the entity. 
You can see there are three calculated fields, those fields are calculated based of the capacity field and the registered table and the waitlist table.
The sql error when trying to save is: "Cannot update the view or function 'SDWorkshop.vWorkshop' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator." 
It does contain a GROUP BY .

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the update option to use store procedures where you can modify the required tables
[Here the docs for do it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, I guess I could have used a stored procedure too but I ended up getting my DBA to create a INSTEAD OF trigger for insert.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_vWorkshop_InsteadOfInsert ON [SDWorkshop].[vWorkshop]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SDWorkshop.Workshop
            ({columns here})

        SELECT      
             {columns here}

        FROM inserted
END

SELECT [Workshop_ID] FROM [SDWorkshop].[Workshop] 
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Workshop_ID] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

The bottom select is needed to return the ID of the newly created row otherwise entity framework thinks nothing was created.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in this way:

Main Model

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RequestTypeId { get; set; }
    public int RequestStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FromUser")]
    public string FromUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ToUser")]
    public string ToUserId { get; set; }
    public string RequestData { get; set; }
    public string RequestResult { get; set; }
    public bool RequestIsActive { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ToUser { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser FromUser { get; set; }

}
```

Model For View

```
public class RequestView
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RequestTypeId { get; set; }
        public string RequestTypeName { get; set; }
        public int RequestStatusId { get; set; }
        public string RequestStatusName { get; set; }
        public string Created { get; set; }

        public string FromUserId { get; set; }
        public string FromUserName { get; set; }

        public string ToUserId { get; set; }
        public string ToUserName { get; set; }
        public string RequestResult { get; set; }
        public bool RequestIsActive { get; set; }

    }
```

and in Entity Configuration:

```
  public class RequestConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<RequestModel>
{
    public RequestConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("QMS_REQUESTS").HasKey(p =>p.Id);


        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("REQUEST_ID").IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.RequestTypeId).HasColumnName("REQUEST_TYPE_ID");
        Property(p => p.RequestData).HasColumnName("REQUEST_DATA").HasMaxLength(800);
        Property(p => p.RequestResult).HasColumnName("REQUEST_RESULT").HasMaxLength(150);
        Property(p => p.RequestStatusId).HasColumnName("REQUEST_STATUS_ID");
        Property(p => p.Created).HasColumnName("REQUEST_CREATED").HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(p => p.RequestIsActive).HasColumnName("REQUEST_IsActive");
        Property(p => p.FromUserId).HasColumnName("FROM_USER");
        Property(p => p.ToUserId).HasColumnName("TO_USER");
    }
}

public class RequestViewConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<RequestView>
{
    public RequestViewConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("VIEW_QMS_REQUESTS").HasKey(p => p.Id);


        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("REQUEST_ID").IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.RequestTypeId).HasColumnName("REQUEST_TYPE_ID");
        Property(p => p.RequestTypeName).HasColumnName("REQUEST_TYPE_NAME");
        Property(p => p.RequestStatusId).HasColumnName("REQUEST_STATUS_ID");
        Property(p => p.RequestStatusName).HasColumnName("REQUEST_STATUS_NAME");
        Property(p => p.RequestResult).HasColumnName("REQUEST_RESULT").HasMaxLength(150);
        Property(p => p.Created).HasColumnName("REQUEST_CREATED").HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(p => p.RequestIsActive).HasColumnName("REQUEST_IsActive");
        Property(p => p.FromUserId).HasColumnName("FROM_USER");
        Property(p => p.FromUserName).HasColumnName("FROM_USERNAME");
        Property(p => p.ToUserId).HasColumnName("TO_USER");
        Property(p => p.ToUserName).HasColumnName("TO_USERNAME");
    }
}
```

And in Migration:

```
  public partial class RequestView : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

                Sql(@"
                CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VIEW_QMS_REQUESTS]
                AS
                SELECT        dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.REQUEST_ID, dbo.VIEW_QMS_COM_REQUEST_TYPES.REQUEST_TYPE_ID, dbo.VIEW_QMS_COM_REQUEST_TYPES.REQUEST_TYPE_NAME_AR AS REQUEST_TYPE_NAME, 
                        dbo.VIEW_QMS_REQUEST_STATUS_TYPES.REQUEST_STATUS_ID, dbo.VIEW_QMS_REQUEST_STATUS_TYPES.REQUEST_STATUS_NAME_AR AS REQUEST_STATUS_NAME, dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.REQUEST_CREATED, 
                        dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.FROM_USER, dbo.AspNetUsers.UserName AS FROM_USERNAME, dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.TO_USER, AspNetUsers_1.UserName AS TO_USERNAME, dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.REQUEST_RESULT, 
                        dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.REQUEST_IsActive
                FROM            dbo.QMS_REQUESTS INNER JOIN
                        dbo.VIEW_QMS_COM_REQUEST_TYPES ON dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.REQUEST_TYPE_ID = dbo.VIEW_QMS_COM_REQUEST_TYPES.REQUEST_TYPE_ID INNER JOIN
                        dbo.VIEW_QMS_REQUEST_STATUS_TYPES ON dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.REQUEST_STATUS_ID = dbo.VIEW_QMS_REQUEST_STATUS_TYPES.REQUEST_STATUS_ID INNER JOIN
                        dbo.AspNetUsers ON dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.FROM_USER = dbo.AspNetUsers.Id INNER JOIN
                        dbo.AspNetUsers AS AspNetUsers_1 ON dbo.QMS_REQUESTS.TO_USER = AspNetUsers_1.Id
                GO
                ");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql(@"DROP VIEW [dbo].[VIEW_QMS_REQUESTS] GO");
    }
```

And in ApplicationDbContext:

```
  public virtual DbSet<RequestModel> Requests { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<RequestView> RequestsView { get; set; }
```

I hope it's clear to you.